# Renaming files in terminal; now no launcher and no dash appear

Tags: nautilus, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.02 on Virtual box (5.0.26 r108824)

Tonight I was batch renaming files via terminal `rename -n 's/^/161102_/' *.gsf` within a specific directory. The renamed files appeared in terminal so i removed the -n. Re running the code the renamed files did not appear in the directory i was working within. I closed nautilus on the hope it would refresh itself. On reopening nautilus the renamed files did not appear and only the original files were visible?

I restarted my machine and i now get no launcher, no dash just my custom desktop wallpaper. I can open a terminal and open nautilus and browse my directories and files. However, when i enter ls in any dir, i get the below

```
jarrod@jarrod-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ ls
jarrod@jarrod-VirtualBox:~/Documents$
```

there are files in this dir which i can see using nautilus.

In terminal if enter

```
sudo su
```

and re-run

```
root@jarrod-VirtualBox:/home/jarrod/Documents# ls
root@jarrod-VirtualBox:/home/jarrod/Documents#
```

I get the same results

On the desktop i can (mouse) right click and get the standard menu popping up (e.g. new folder, new document, open terminal etc)

If wait for Ubuntu to time out and the login dialogue box appears i can see the dash and launcher in the background, but when i login as a guest the above issues are encountered.

Any help to solve my issues would be great!

Also what happened to my renamed files? Are they the root of my issues?

Thanks in advance!